# Where are these 3 white flagstaffs in front of a commemorative stone, river and valleys?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth

I cut out my sibling's head from this picture. Sibling thinks this was in North America but can't remember. Perhaps Europe? Anyone recognize this?

We see a plaque with text on a stone like a commemoration? We see a boat cruising.  We can't figure out what those black beams rods are behind the three white poles and people are sitting on the shore line.

[image]

Comment: I'll guess that the "black beam rods" are part of an anchor, a non-uncommon object at a monument at the edge of big water.

Comment: The one on the left is for sure an anchor.

Comment: The one on the right sits at a different angle, suggesting it's a difference piece. But the shape of the "fluke" is discernible as a common anchor shape. So...two anchors.

Comment: At least your sibling remembers which countries they have visited? I would guess it's UK but...

Comment: Check the metadata from the original image for clues.

Comment: If you have a higher resolution photo, you might be able to read some of the inscription on the plaque?

Comment: I have voted to close as this question really does not have enough details, it is a miracle it has gotten an answer.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This picture was taken at the "Landing Memorial" in [Saint-Tropez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Tropez), Côte d'Azur, France. The memorial honors the American, British and French landing troops who came ashore in the Provence on the 15th of August 1944.

The memorial also honors the French commandos led by Henri D'Astier de la Vigerie, who landed on Saint-Tropez on the 17th of August 1944.

More information about the memorial, including the text of the two inscriptions, is available on the Page ["Les monuments aux morts" of the University of Lille, France](https://monumentsmorts.univ-lille.fr/monument/33222/saint-tropez-autre/).

See also [this page on tracesofwar.com](https://www.tracesofwar.com/sights/83625/Landing-memorial-Saint-Tropez.htm).

Here's a view of the monument from [Google Streetview](https://goo.gl/maps/Vfu47pCFM3cvB53P6):

[image]

Here's a [different streetview](https://goo.gl/maps/VV8gATu99Bpiseav8), giving a better view of the two anchors:

[image]

Comment: I have never studied French, yet I can almost read both of those inscriptions, from a mostly English language background.  A lot of the words in the original language are able to cross language barriers pretty well, even outside of the Romance family.

Comment: They've been alternately killing each other and sneaking across for a bottle of plonk and a shag for the last 900 years so that's not really surprising.

Comment: @PeterWone Joined just to upvote your comment! But more like 954 years :)

Comment: @user7761803  Since long before "1066 and all that". That was just another chapter in the tale. WTC was, after all, claiming his alleged right to a throne based on what was even then 'history'.

Comment: For interest - how did you identify the site - somewhere you knew of or ...?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: No, i did a reverse image search, based on a rotated and cropped version of the original pic. After correcting the slight rotation to the right, and cropping most of the pic at the top and bottom, yandex returned some more pics of the memorial, which allowed identification. In most cases, correcting rotation or perspective and cropping to "relevant" parts makes it more probable that a reverse image search will lead to good results. I've used yandex since it's far better than google regarding reverse image search. Bing is useful sometimes, too.

Comment: Usually Spanish is a lot easier for me to make out than French.  It may change a little bit depending on geography, but people (particularly, if they're not in Louisiana) living closer to Mexico than to Canada or France are exposed to a lot more Spanish and probably have an easier time with it.